# Mathematical expression calculation in Javasscript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that have a equation on below how to i calculate the output

```
  var equation=  "((35.8/100)*100)*10%"
```

I used `eval` in JS , but eval cannot support percentage , anyone can help it how to figure out, Thanks

Comment: Please don't tag your question with libraries if it concerns a vanilla js operation or logical problem

Comment: 10% is x 0.1. Highschool math, dude.

Comment: Hahah, correct.

Comment: equation is a string  here is the problem i faced

Comment: As `%` means something completely different in js, you will need to handle percentage yourself. An easy approach could be replacing each `x * y%` with `x * y/100` and each `x + y%` with `x * (1 + y/100)` and then `eval` the complete formula. Depending on the complexity of your formulas, this might be enough

Comment: I'm positive I saw this *exact* same question recently.  Can't find it though.

Comment: if you change 10% to 0.1...then you can just use eval

Comment: Inform the user of said calculator that they gave invalid input.

Comment: @ZahidRahman - did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular expression to get the percent, divide it by 100, and put back the decimal.

```js
var equation=  "((35.8/100)*100)*10.1%"; 

var regex = /\d*\.?\d*(?=%)/;
var percent = equation.match(regex)[0];
var decimal = percent/100;
equation = equation.replace(percent+"%", decimal);

console.log(percent);
console.log(decimal);
console.log(equation);
console.log(eval(equation));
```

Comment: [Now I have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - that's why I only used it to isolate the percent string, and not do the replacement, or anything else.  Use it for what's easy, but don't try and shoe-horn it in to do other things.  But in terms of string matching, it's pretty great.

Comment: Yes, except you've neglected to account for (for instance) multiple percentages (`*10%)*10%)`). The main problem with a regex is that it is extremely brittle. You normally use it when you *want* it to be extremely brittle (for example, input validation), not when you need it to work for a veriaty of cases :)

Comment: I don't think this solution would work with fractional percentages, e.g. `10.1%`?

Comment: didnot work on when percentage is fraction 10.1%? thanks @amy , If you solve it will greatful

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I solved the problem as stated.  I also didn't handle exponents, but are we really supposed to handle every possible case?  I thought the idea here was to answer the question and point the person in the right direction. If it needs to handle multiple instances, even people who don't know regular expressions can do a while loop.

Comment: @ZahidRahman - I've updated the answer to handle decimal percentages. Please select this as the correct answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Why not use `const percent = /((?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)%/g; console.log(eval(equation.replace(percent, '($1/100)')));`?

Comment: Or if you want to continue matching the pattern you currently have, use `const percent = /(\d+\.?\d*)%/g;` instead. (changed first `*` to `+` otherwise `.%` could be matched, which is invalid)